# scope calling functions inside functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Hope somebody finds the time to explain little about functions in functions and scoping.
I am trying to understand little more on functions and scope of variables and found a quite good tutorial, but this part I just do not get.

**The task:**

Create a function sum that will work like that: `sum(a)(b) = a+b` and accepts any number of brackets. Examples:

```
sum(1)(2) == 3
sum(5)(-1)(2) == 6
```

**The solution:**

```
function sum(a) {

    var sum = a;

    function f(b){
        sum += b;
        return f;
    }

    f.toString = function() { return sum };

    return f;         //line 12
}

alert( sum(1)(2) );   // 3e
```

**The Explanation:**

To make `sum(1)` callable as `sum(1)(2)`, it must return a function.
The function can be either called or converted to a number with `valueOf`.
The solution is really self-explanatory:

**My interpretation:**

This `f` in `function f(b)` returned to the scope, which is from line 02 - 12.
The `f` in `f.toString`, is the currently returned `f` from `function(b)`
The next `return f` returns to the scope which is outside the function `sum(a)`.

**Problem:**

I cannot figure out, where I need to think differently, because like I described above, the function would not be called again, so where is the part of the code, that make the 'several parentheses' possible?

Moreover, did I correctly assume where the `f`s are returned? Would be great if somebody would give some explanations.

Comment: Calling `sum` with one parameter returns a function that can be called with the next parameter. This is called "currying"; calling a function with one argument until all the arguments have been evaluated, then return the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closure in JavaScript - whats wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066322/closure-in-javascript-whats-wrong)

Comment: What do you mean by "*The next `return f` returns to the scope which is outside the function sum(a)*"?

Comment: @Bergi thank you for clearing me from the wrong. Currying is indead a different beast altogether. A wonderfull question, thanks for asking this, it will create a large set of answers with juicy info

Answer (score 7):

The function `sum` returns a function, which we refer to as `f`.

The function `f` also returns a function: in fact, the function `f` returns *itself*.

When the function `f` is defined inside of `sum`, it gets permanent access to all variables currently visible in the scope chain. Here, it includes the locally-defined variable `sum` (the local running sum tally) and `f` (the function itself). (A "closure" is what we call the functional code of `f` along with all its in-scope variables.)

Because `f` returns itself, you can chain `f` with repeated calls:

```
var this_is_f = sum(1);
var same_f_again = this_is_f(2);
var f_a_third_time = same_f_again(3);
```

Or simply:

```
sum(1)(2)(3);
```

It is important to note that in my first example, I don't create new functions; instead, I just refer to the exact same function object with three different identifiers.

Each call to `sum` creates a brand-new `f` with a new local `sum` in its scope (here, I mean the local `sum` defined on the first line of the function named `sum`). However, calling the function `sum` does not clobber any old `f`, because each call to `sum` instantiates a new `f` (and knows nothing about any other `f`s that have been created on prior calls to `sum`). That way, you can have multiple tallies running:

```
var first_tally = sum(1)(2);   // first: 3
var second tally = sum(4)(5);  // second: 9
first_tally(3);   // first: 6
second_tally(6);  // second: 15
```

The reason you're able to see a meaningful result at any time is that `f` stingifies to the value of `sum`, instead of showing you its source code.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. function f returns f. But whereto? What "contains" f? or different: where is the returnd f going to ... there is no var which it is assigned. to. Meru

Comment: @Meru It's going nowhere currently... But you were aware of this disturbing reality, right? I guess, you just didn't want to admit :D

Comment: @Meru Ok, I'm joking. `f` lives in a parallel universe, where no-one can go but `f`, created at the time of calling the `sum` function (which is like the big bang in a way). Then, no need to use `var` since writing `function f` produces the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you take this code and simplify it to the bare minimum I would be easier to understand. Take a function `add` that sums only 2 numbers:

```
function add(x,y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

The above is a "normal" function. If you don't pass all the arguments you'll get unexpected results.

Now, if you want a function that adds 2 to any number, you could partially apply an argument to `add`, for example:

```
function add2(x) {
  return add(2, x);
}
```

But in JavaScript we have first class functions (objects that can be passed around), so a function can take functions as inputs and return other functions. This is where "currying" comes in handy. While "partial application" lets you fix function arguments, "currying" takes a function of many arguments and breaks it down into a function of a single argument that returns another function of one single argument until all the arguments have been evaluated, in order, and then returns the result. For example:

```
function add(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

Now you can create a function `add2` by currying the function `add`:

```
var add2 = add(2);
add2(1); //=> 3
```

The normal function and the curried one have equivalent computations where:

```
add(1, 2) === add(1)(2)
```

This is what makes "several parentheses" possible.

In JavaScript "scope" and "closure" refer to functions but they're different concepts. A "scope" determines the reach/privacy of your variables while a "closure" lets you encapsulate code and carry it around. In the curried function above the variable `x` is kept in memory through closure because it's referenced inside the returned function object.

A particular limitation of "currying" is that you can't have functions of dynamic arity; the number of arguments must be fixed. This is not the case in the code you post where your `sum` function must be able to add a new number to the previous sum indefinitely.

Similarly to "currying" there's the idea of "generators"; a pattern to model sequences of lazy computation, in this case just adding a number to the previous sum on demand.

```
function sum(a) { // begin closure
  var sum = a; // kept in memory...
  function f(b) {
    sum += b; //...because you use it here
    return f;
  }
  f.toString = function() { return sum };
  return f;
} // end closure
```

A different (maybe more clear) way to express your code would be to return an object to chain the computations, where you can either add a new number to the previous sum, or get the total sum so far:

```
function add(a) {
  var sum = a;
  return {
    plus: function(b) {
      sum += b;
      return this;
    },
    sum: function() {
      return sum;
    }
  }
}

add(1).plus(2).plus(3).sum(); //=> 6
```

In your code the returned function `f` acts as `plus` and `toString` as `sum` which retrieves the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your call-chain "sum()" is only once called. How did you mean it: Would this be the function-calls "you" write, or the code executes it? If it is the order in which it is executed, considering a call "sum(1)(2)(3), then I have the question: Why is sum() only called once?

Answer (score 1):

1. Line 01-13 defines the function `sum` within the global scope.
2. Line 15 calls `sum` and changes scope to inside the function.

   1. The variables `a` and `sum` and the closure function `f` are all defined in the function's scope - with the `sum` variable hiding the function definition from the global scope.
   2. I'll skip over the `toString` bit here as its not important till later (when it gets very important).
   3. The function `sum` finally returns a reference to the closure function `f` to the global scope as an anonymous function (since `f` can only be referenced by name from within its containing function's scope).
3. Back to line 15 - `sum(1)(2)` is the same as `(sum(1))(2)` and since `sum(1)` returns `f` then this can be reduced to `(f)(2)` or, more simply, `f(2)`.

   1. Calling `f(2)` adds `2` to `sum` - `sum` is defined in two scopes: as a function in the global scope; and as a variable (currently assigned the value of `1`) within that function which hides the definition from the global scope - so, in `f`, the `sum` variable is set to `1+2=3`.
   2. Finally, in `f`, the function returns itself.
4. Back, again, to line 15 - `f(2)` returns `f` (although the named function `f` cannot be referenced in the global scope and, again , is treated as an anonymous function)
5. `alert()` is processed and the anonymous function (referred to as `f`) is converted to a string to be alerted; normally when `alert()` is called on a function it will display the source for the function (try commenting out Line 10 to see this). However, since `f` has a `toString` method (Line 10) then this is invoked and the value of `sum` (as defined in the function containing `f`) is returned and `3` is alerted.

Comment: So, the "f.toString" is only called once, whereas "function f(b)" is calld twice (in case of two parameters in calling sum)? The parameter of "f", that "b", is always the parameter, of that call: sum (1)(2)?

Comment: No - `alert( sum(1)(2) )` is the same as `alert( ( ( sum(1) )(2) ).toString() )` which can be evaluated in the order:  `sum(1)` is called returning `f` then `f(2)` is called returning `f` and finally f.toString() is called; so `sum()`, `f()` and `f.toString()` are all each called only once.

Comment: @ MTO, thanks. Therewith - with a call 'sum(1)(2)(3)' the callings would be: sum(1) > returning f > f(2) > returning f > f(3) > returning f, and because no other parenthesis are there anymore > f.toString() is called. Is this correct?

Comment: `sum(1)` which returns `f` > `f(2)` which returns `f` > `alert(f)` which implicitly is converted to `alert( f.toString() )` and `f.toString()` returns `3`.

Comment: @MT0 this is the only answer that I easly understand. I don't know why no one did not give an upvote to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are **3** concepts being played here

- **closures** (no scope).
- functions are **first class *OBJECTS*** in javascript (allows for chaining `f(a)(b)(c)`). There's no need to save a handle to the function to call it later.

I'll give you a run-down and then add some extra explanations afterwards

```
function sum(a) {
  // when sum is called, sumHolder is created
  var sumHolder = a;
  // the function f is created and holds sumHolder (a closure on the parent environment)
  function f(b) {
    // do the addition
    sumHolder += b;
    // return a FUNCTION
    return f;
  }
  // change the functions default toString method (another closure)
  f.toString = function() {return sumHolder;}
  // return a FUNCTION
  return f
}
/*
 * ok let's explain this piece by piece
 * 
 * you call sum with a parameter
 *  - parameter is saved into sumHolder
 *  - a function is returned
 * 
 * you call the returned function f with another parameter
 * EXPLANATION: { sum(a) } returns f, so let's call f as this => {...}()
 *  - this private (priviledged) function adds whatever it's been passed
 *  - returns itself for re-execution, like a chain
 * 
 * when it all ends {{{{}(a)}(b)}(c)} the remainder is a FUNCTION OBJECT
 * this remainder is special in that it's toString() method has been changed
 *  so we can attempt to cast (juggle) it to string for (loose) comparison
 * 
 */
```

The concept behind closures is quite easy to understand but it's application make's your head spin until you get used to the idea that **there is no function scope in javascript**, there is **closures** and these are powerfull critters indeed

```
// this anonymous function has access to the global environment and window object
(function()
  {// start this context
    var manyVars, anotherFunc;
    function someFunc() {
      // has access to manyVars and anotherFunc
      // creates its own context
    };
    anotherFunc = function () {
      // has access to the same ENVIRONMENT
      // creates its own context
    };
  }// whatever is in these keys is context that is not destroyed and
  //  will exist within other functions declared inside
  //  those functions have closure on their parent's environment
  //  and each one generates a new context
)();
```

Functions are first class objects. What does this mean? I'm not sure myself but let me explain with some further examples:

```
// how about calling an anonymous function just as its created
// *cant do the next line due to a language constraint
// function(){}()
// how about a set of parens, this way the word "function" is not the first expression
(function(){}());
// the function was created, called and forgotten
// but the closure inside MAY STILL EXIST
function whatDoIReturn() {
  return function (){alert('this is legal');return 'somevalue';}();// and executed
}// returns 'somevalue'
```

Don't take this word for word. Go look for other people's code, check the **Crockford** and ask any and all questions that come up

Comment: Of course there is function scope! What did you mean by that? Also, how to "*check the **Crockford***"?

Comment: Btw, functions returning functions is not called currying, this is just functional programming. Check [what *currying* actually it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and notice that it actually is only defined for functions with a defined number of parameters.

Comment: @Bergi on the matter of currying you are absolutely correct. I will erase all content on that subject

Comment: @Bergi when people come from other languages and see the `{}` (blocks) in a function definition they mistakenly think that scope works exactly the same as in C, PHP<5.3, Java... but the fact is that it doesn't. the space inside the function brackets creates a _spacial_ scope that will be saved and passed to other functions defined inside it. Some people like to play with these _hidden_ scopes by creating what would look like private members in Java. As for Crockford: http://javascript.crockford.com/. He has videos that leave everything clear and in the open

Comment: @hanzo2001: So you mean: "There is only function scope, no block scope (as in other languages)"

Comment: @Bergi yeah, that would sound like it, but I would change that to "functions create special scopes that allow the creation of closures, do not treat them as `function scope` that you find in other languages, the closure is much more powerful and less forgiving"

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through the function line by line:

```
function sum(a) {
```

This part is pretty self-explanatory; we have a function named `sum` which accepts an argument `a`.

```
    var sum = a
```

Here we have a local variable called `sum` that is set to the value of the argument that is passed in.

```
    function f(b) {
        sum += b
        return f
    }
```

This is an *inner* function called `f` that accepts an argument called `b`. This `b` is then added to the value of `sum` from the *outer* scope (i.e., inside the scope of the function that is also called `sum`). After that, the function returns *itself*.

```
    f.toString = function() { return sum }
```

This is the fun part! When you normally `console.log` a function, it will just spit out the function's source. Here we are redefining the `toString` method to instead be a function that spits out the value of `sum`. **This is why you end up seeing the running total that is displayed instead of the function's source *even though* what you are returning is still a function.**

Finally we have:

```
    return f
```

So you basically have a function `sum`, returning a function *that returns itself*. The function `sum` basically sets everything up, but after calling `sum(3)`, you then work with `f`, which you repeatedly call.

So the first time you call `sum`, you essentially get back this function:

```
function f(b) {
   sum += b; //value of sum is 3
   return f;
}
```

In this context, the value of `sum` will be the value of `a` that you passed into the initial call of the function `sum`. However, since the `toString` of `f` has been redefined, you only see the value `3`. Then let's say you do `sum(3)(4)`.

You get back, as before:

```
function f(b) {
   sum += b; //value of sum is 3
   return f;
}
```

But *then* you are actually calling `f` with an argument of `4` (basically `f(4)`). Since `f` is an inner function, it has full access to the scope of its parent function. This parent function (`sum`) is maintaining the the running total in a variable called `sum`, which is accessible to `f`. So when you now call `f(4)`, you have `b` set to `4` and `sum` having a value of `3`:

```
function f(b) { //b is 4
   sum += b; //value of sum is 3 + 4, which is 7
   return f;
}
```

So with each subsequent pair parentheses you are making repeated calls to the *same* `f` which is maintaining a running tally.

Another way is to think of `sum` as a kind of factory that can give you different `f`'s, all of which keep *their own* running tallies (basically behaving like accumulators):

```
var firstSum = sum(4);
var secondSum = sum(2);

firstSum(5); //equivalent to sum(4)(5) returns 9
secondSum(2); //equivalent to sum(2)(2) returns 4
```