# JavaScript: composable self-referential function for counting / obtaining property from bound function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is impossible or not.

Consider this function:

```
function p(num) {
    if (!num) num = 1;
    return p.bind(null, num + 1);
}
```

if you call `p()`, inside the function `num = 1`, if you call `p()()`, `num = 2` and so on. But, there is no way to actually return or obtain `num` from `p` because it always returns a bound copy of itself with the number trapped in its unexecutable closure.

Anyway, I'm curious (a) if there is a way to pull the argument out of the bound function, or (b) there is another way to count in this fashion.

Comment: How about returning an `object` ?.. `return {num:num,function:p.bind(null, num + 1)}`

Comment: Have a look at [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Wow, that is such a smart solution. I was going to do something weird with generators.

Comment: @AllTheTime, how about you tell us what you're actually trying to do with it? Show us another piece of code that would use this. I bet there's a better design.

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers depending on what you want.  If you simply want something "imperative" and "stateful":

```
    function p() {
      if (!p.num) p.num = 0;
      p.num = 1 + p.num;
      return p;
    }

    p();
    p.num; // 1
    p();
    p.num; // 2
    p()();
    p.num; // 4
    p()()();
    p.num; // 7
```

Or if you want it to be "stateless":

```
    function p() {
      p.num = 0;
      function gen_next(prev) {
        function next() {
          return gen_next(next);
        }
        next.num = prev.num + 1;
        return next;
      }
      return gen_next(p);
    }

    p().num; // 1
    p()().num; // 2
    p()()().num; // 3
    p()().num; // still 2
    p().num; // still 1
```