# turn javascript closure into a curried function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, currying

I'm learning about currying and I decided to try to make a curried minimum function called `getMin`.

To my understanding, this means that I should be able to call 
`getMinimum(5)(2)(6)` and have it return `2`.

I tried to implement this with a simple closure and I came up with something that returns numbers instead of functions.  Here's my code:

```
function getMin(val){
    var min = val
    function calc(num){
        if(num<min){
            // set new minimum
            min = num
            return num
        }
        else {
            return min
        }
    }
    return calc
}


var x = getMin(5) // => 5
console.log(x(6))
console.log(x(4))
console.log(x(8))
console.log(x(2))
```

This logs:

```
5
4
4
2
```

This doesn't meet the requirements of currying.

So as I consider how I might change this function so that it returns a function, I run into a problem.  Every time the curried function is called with a number argument, it should return the minimum (a number), but if I am understanding this correctly, it should also return a function (so that it can be called once again with another number).  How does this work?

Comment: you never log `x` which is the return of `getMin(5)`. That's the function

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function, which returns the result, if a primitive value is required, otherwise a function.

```js
function getMinimum(m) {
    function min(v) {
        m = Math.min(m, v);
        return min;
    }
    min.toString = _ => m;
    return min;
}


console.log(getMinimum(5)(2)(6));
console.log(getMinimum(3)(2)(1)(-1000));
```

Comment: @MoritzRoessler, that does not work here, because this implementation of `console.log` needs a string, whereas `valueOf` with a number yields the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are misunderstanding currying. It doesn't mean that your function should take an arbitrary amount of arguments (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572) on how to do that while allowing multiple chained calls), but only that it should takes only a single argument value at a time. Your `getMin` function already *is* curried, it has the signature `number -> (number -> number)` (taking two numbers, returning one). If it wasn't curried you'd have to call it as `getMin(5, 4)`.

Comment: If getMin is already curried, shouldn't I be able to call `getMin(5)(4)(6)` and get `4`?  When I try this I get `getMin(...)(...) is not a function`

Comment: I see your point; you're not necessarily saying the function is valid, just that it's curried.