# how to write a single function named `add`. Such that once it has received 2 arguments, it returns the sum of the 2 values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

How to write a single function named `add`. Such that once it has received 2 arguments, it returns the sum of the 2 values. Assume all values are numbers.:

for example
// add(1, 2) = 3

// add(1)(2) = 3

// add()(1)()(2) = 3

// add()(1)(2) = 3

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: `function calcSum(a,b){

var ab = function (b) {
 return a+b;
}

if(typeof a == 'undefined'){
 return ab;
}

if(typeof b == 'undefined'){
 return ab;
}
else {
 return ab(b);
}


}`

Comment: Thanks, I hope my answer will help

Answer (score 1):

Too easy:

```
 const curry = (fn, ...previous) => (...args) => args.length + previous.length >= fn.length ? fn(...previous, ...args) : curry(fn, ...previous, ...args);

 const add = curry((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried
>
> ```
> function calcSum(a,b){ var ab = function (b) { return a+b; } if(typeof a == 'undefined'){ return ab; } if(typeof b == 'undefined'){ return ab; } else { return ab(b); } }
> ```

This doesn't look too bad - it's working for `calcSum(1,2)` and `calcSum(1)(2)`. However, you're not correctly treating the cases where nothing (or `undefined`) is passed:

- `calcSum()` should return a function that still expects two arguments
- `calcSum(1)()` = `ab()` should return a function that still expects one argument

You already matched the first case, but you returned `ab` (which takes only one value) instead of `calcSum` (the function that would take two values). To fix this, use

```
function calcSum(a,b){
    var ab = function(b) {
        if (typeof b == 'undefined') return ab;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        else return a+b;
    }
    if (typeof a == 'undefined') return calcSum;
//                                      ^^^^^^^^
    if (typeof b == 'undefined') return ab; // actually you don't need this, ab(b) already handles this case as well now
    else return ab(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making me understand how to think and what I missed. Also how to make it work for not just 2 but 'n' number of arguments?

Comment: @sampathNeeru That's really hard (and not particularly useful anyway) since you never know when to return another function or the result. There are [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572) though.

Answer (score 0):

```
let add = (...a)=>a.length==2 ? a[0]+a[1] : (...b)=>add(...a.concat(b));
```

The idea is simple... we declare a variadic function and if we got two elements then we're done (and return the sum) otherwise we return a new variadic function that will collect more elements and call the function itself recursively passing what got already `a` concatenated with the new elements `b`.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @sampathNeeru: added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this suggestion:

```
function add(){
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue)
}

// you can also add as many argument you want.
const b = add(1,2,3,4); // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const add = (...toAddArr) => {
    let result = 0;
    for (let toAddNr of toAddArr) {
        result += toAddNr;
    }
    return result;
}
```

console.log(add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

This example uses the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get unlimited arguments and pass it as an array and the [for/of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over it.