# Functional Sum - why use toString on a function

Tags: javascript, closures

Just started doing some JS stuff and can't get my head around something. I have the following task:

> Write a function that adds a number passed to it to an internal sum
> and returns itself with its internal sum set to the new value, so it
> can be chained in a functional manner.  Input: Your function needs to
> take one numeric argument. Output: Your function needs to return itself
> with an updated context.

I came up with the following code after some hints from here and there:

```js
function add(num) {
  let sum = num;

  function func(num2) {
    sum += num2;
    
    return func;
  }

  func.toString = function() {return sum;};
  return func;
}

console.log(
  add(1)
);
console.log(
  add(1)(6)(-3)
);
```

What exactly do `func.toString = function() {return sum;}` and `return func` do? Before that I get it - closure and returning a function and etc.

Comment: Which last two lines? The last two of `add`, or the last two of the example `add(1) ...`?

Comment: func.toString = function() {return sum;};
  return func;

Comment: If you comment out the line and run the same examples again, you can see exactly why it was there - the result of `add(1)` and `add(1)(6)(-3)` is `func`, so without changing its `toString` method you don't see the resulting value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So basically I rewrite the toString method of the function so I can see the resulting sum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572