# How do I make `foo[1] ==1; foo[1][2]==3; foo[1][2][3]==6` work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

How do I define `foo` to make the following code work correctly as expected (in JavaScript)?

```js
foo[1] + 1             // 2
foo[1][2] + 1          // 4
foo[10][20][30] + 1    // 61
foo[100][200][300] + 1 // 601
```

This is an interview question I once met.

Comment: @Phil Sure it's possible :-)

Comment: That a proxy is allowed is Valuable Information.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's a puzzle. Anything is "allowed" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a new take on the old [variadic chainable `sum` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832891/1048572) puzzle, with proxy member access instead of function calls. The [possible approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572) are still the same though, and the `…+1` gives away that they are looking for the `valueOf` solution. In the same vein, `foo+1` would be `1` and `+foo`/`Number(foo)` would be `0`.

```js
const handler = {
    get(target, propName, receiver) {
        if (typeof propName == 'string' && /^\d+$/.test(propName))
            return sumProxy(target + parseInt(propName, 10));
        else
            return Reflect.get(target, propName, receiver);
    }
};
function sumProxy(value) {
    return new Proxy({
        valueOf() { return value; }
    }, handler);
}
const foo = sumProxy(0);

console.log(foo + 1);                // 1
console.log(foo[1] + 1);             // 2
console.log(foo[1][2] + 1);          // 4
console.log(foo[10][20][30] + 1);    // 61
console.log(foo[100][200][300] + 1); // 601
```