# create a function that will add numbers together when called in succession

Tags: javascript

I need a single function which will return the below output.

```
add(1)     =  1
add(1)(2)  =  3
add(1)(2)(3) = 6
```

like wise the function should return the result.

I want a function `function add(){}` to perform the above task.

Please help me with an optimized solution

Comment: no code.. no solution. What's your try?

Comment: Are you needing it to except any number of parameters or will it always be 3 or less?

Comment: Homework ? ..............

Comment: function add(a){return function(b){return a + b}} I tried in this way, but it will work out for only two function call. Since i didnt get the logic I posted to the forum. @AmitJoki

Comment: @ChrisJ - It can be any number. I

Comment: @Raj is it always three parameters that are passed?

Comment: @AmitJoki - it can be one , two three, ....n

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832891/javascript-sum-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @ermouth for [initial code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457272/887539).

```
var add = (function() {
    var factory = function(value) {
        var fn = function(num) {
            return factory(value + num);
        };
        // This is the main hack: 
        // We will return a function that when compared / concatted will call .toString and return a number.
        // Never use this in production code...
        fn.toString = function() {
            return value;
        };
        return fn;
    };
    return factory(0);
})();

add(1); // 1
add(1); // 1
add(1)(2); // 3
add(1)(2)(3); // 6
```

But beware of equal comparation:

```
add(2) == add(2) // false
add(2) > add(1) // true
add(2) < add(1) // false
```

Comment: Nice improvement, thanks. But I’m ermouth, not ermounth )

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your function in a closure and redefine function’s `toString` method.

```
var add = (function(initNum) {
    var current = initNum || 0;
    var fn = function(num) {
        current += num;
        return fn;
    };
    fn.toString = function() {
        return current
    };
    return fn;
})(0);
```

`add(1)` → `1`, then `add(2)(3)(4)` → `10`

Comment: This will not work: `add(1) // 1` and again `add(1) // 2` ...

Comment: @null, oh, I missed that it must restart ( Sorry.

Comment: And what does `2+3+4` equal? 10 or ... 9? ;)

Comment: @null Surely **1+** 2+3+4 is 10. I mean I misread it must be re-entrant. 
But question is really brilliant – so please, tell why exactly did you mark it as ‘Too broad’? I’m new at Stackoverflow and do not understand this particular application of the policy. Sorry for off-topic.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
function add() {
   var erg = 0;
   for(var i in arguments)
       erg += arguments[i];
   return erg; 
}
```

you can call it like add(1,2,3);

Comment: I dont wanna call the way you mentioned add(1,2,3). It should be add(1)(2)(3)

Comment: for what is this for... why do you want to have a function in a function in a function?

Comment: this is asked in an interview today.

Comment: @Cracker0dks because he simply wants currying?

Answer (score -3):

**Either you were given a trick question, or you've misunderstood the problem**.

You cannot write a function that does this in pure JavaScript (or, for that matter, almost any other language). The problem is that it has to return a number the last time it's called, and a function at all other times. **This would be doable *if* you knew in advance how many times your function is going to be called, but if I understand your question correctly, then you don't know that in advance**. You'd need to be able to foretell the future to know when the function would be called for the last time.

**You could also do this in a language with macros that let you inspect the syntax of your code as it's being run**. This would let you know how long the current chain of calls is, so you'd know when to return a number instead of a function. But JavaScript doesn't do this; in fact, most languages don't.

Is it possible that your interviewers were looking for an add() function that takes a variable number of arguments? That's much easier:

```
function add() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(
        arguments,
        function (sum, next) {
            return sum + next;
        },
        0
    );
}
```

Comment: seems to not working.

Comment: You are definitely wrong – we can redefine `.toString` method of the function (yes, function is object). See my answer.

Comment: @JERmouth: Your method gets the job done within the specific context of an interview question, but the side effects of overriding `Function.prototype.toString` are likely to cause problems if you try to integrate it into things like module systems or OO libraries. I'd argue that any interviewer devious enough to ask a question like this is also likely to talk about these kinds of problems.

Comment: Yes, it's a hack, very rare. But what kind of problems exactly you think may happen?