# Convert functional js function to general case

Tags: javascript

I wonder how i can convert this **curry function** to work with n number of variables instead of 2.

**so for example i want to invoke**:

***curry(mul)(3)(3)(3) -> and get 27***
(with a fixed version of curry)

```
function curry(fn) {
  return function() {
    if (fn.length > arguments.length) {
      var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
      var args = slice.apply(arguments); // get arguments as args array
      return function() {
        return fn.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)));
      };
    }
    return fn.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}

// mul is just an example it can be any function....
function mul(x, y) {
  console.log(x * y)
}

curry(mul)(11)(5)
```

Comment: how do you know the end of the end of the arguments for returning the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variadic curried sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832891/variadic-curried-sum-function)

Comment: i guess by remembering the original number of function arguments length

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate. It does indeed answer your question.

Comment: but here u force the client to write the curried version. i want just to use a general function

Answer (score 0):

This question makes me think of food .. but you can try this version:

```js
const curry = (fn, ...args) =>
  args.length < fn.length ? (...args2) => curry(fn, ...args, ...args2) : fn(...args);

const mul = (a, b, c) => console.log(a * b * c);

curry(mul)(3)(3)(3)
curry(mul)(3, 3)(3)
curry(mul, 3, 3, 3, 3) // extra parameters are ignored by mul
```

IE version here [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20curry%20%3D%20(fn...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20curry%20%3D%20(fn%2C%20...args)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20args.length%20%3C%20fn.length%20%3F%20(...args2)%20%3D%3E%20curry(fn%2C%20...args%2C%20...args2)%20%3A%20fn(...args)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mul%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b%2C%20c)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(a%20*%20b%20*%20c)%3B)