# How to check number of functions chained?

Tags: javascript, currying

I'm trying to solve the following problem on CodeWars: [A Chain adding function](https://www.codewars.com/kata/539a0e4d85e3425cb0000a88):

> We want to create a function that will add numbers together when
> called in succession.
>
> ```
> add(1)(2);
> // returns 3
> ```
>
> We also want to be able to continue to add numbers to our chain.
>
> ```
> add(1)(2)(3); // 6
> add(1)(2)(3)(4); // 10
> add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5); // 15
> ```
>
> and so on.
>
> A single call should return the number passed in.
>
> ```
>  add(1); // 1
> ```
>
> We should be able to store the returned values and reuse them.
>
> ```
> var addTwo = add(2);
> addTwo; // 2
> addTwo + 5; // 7
> addTwo(3); // 5
> addTwo(3)(5); // 10
> ```
>
> We can assume any number being passed in will be valid whole number.

I tried for many hours but to no avail. Like for eg.

```
add(1)(2)(4) <--- 3 chained functions
```

I learned about what "currying" is but returning a function inside my main function would only satisfy `add(1)(2)` <-- 2 chained functions. Again, I'm trying to chain any number of functions here and I can't seem to figure it out.

If the sample test is `add(5)(13)(3)(10)(5)(6)(20)` that's 7 functions chained...I can't possibly type 7 functions in a row return inside one before another except for the first one (main function).

I would like to ask is there any way to check the length of chained functions? Aside from my question, I would appreciate some tips, I'm not asking for a full blown answer.

Comment: You can't check the "length" of the chain; nothing knows the length in the runtime, it's just a sequence of expressions being evaluated.

Comment: You need Objec.prototype.valueOf(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: They are not asking to count the number of calls. They are just asking for the sum: [Variadic curried sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832891)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't possibly type 7 functions in a row return inside one before another

That is why you need to create a recursive solution, so that it can work for any chain length.

I should add that in order to solve this you must look really well at exactly what is *tested*. Here is one test:

```
Test.expect(add(1)(2)(3) == 6);
```

Pay special attention to the equality operator that is used. This should give you a hint at how it can be possible to return a value that can both serve for further chaining, *and* can be equal to a number at the same time.

Hint 1:

> `==` is not the same kind of equality as `===`

Hint 2:

> `valueOf`

Hint 3:

> Functions are objects. They can have custom properties like any other object.

Hint 4:

> Make sure to return a function that has a custom `valueOf` method that returns the current sum value.

Hint 5:

> Use a recursive call, passing it the sum of:
>  1. the argument passed to the outermost function call
>  2. the argument passed to the function that is returned